# What is this net in the big airport battle?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war

In the big airport battle in *Captain America: Civil War*, when Falcon uses Redwing (his drone) to knock Iron Man out of the sky, there's a brief shot of what appears to be some sort of net flying off from the point of impact.
[image]

As seen here: Falcon (top left), Iron Man's feet (bottom right), Redwing (bottom center), the net (top center).

It definitely looks like a net.  It's square, rather than circular like Spider-Man's webs, and it appears to be weighted around the outer edge.  But no one in the cast has ever been seen using a weighted net in their fighting, as far as I remember.  So what is this net, and why is it going flying off when Redwing hits Iron Man?

Answer (score 4):

It's obviously an Anti-Drone net.

Stark did research on all potential enemies before the fight. Which is why he brought Spidy in to fight. He knew Redwing would be used and came prepared for a way to catch it. Nets are the ideal way to catch drones. Large surface area, low weight, and easy to store. The net ideally prevents the captured drone from being damaged.

It's there because Stark fired it at Redwing right after being hit. His aim was thrown off by the attack.

Comment: I guess that makes more sense!

Comment: @ cde I think the 'obviously' is unnecessary in your answer. Unless one has military experience with drones, it's not "obvious."